# Subscription to observable does not trigger value update

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have an angular app that occasionally needs to sync data from a server. I would like to display the time of when the last synchronization was executed.

I already have a function that gets this time, since I use it to only synchronize changes made after the last sync:

```js
fetchLastSyncDate(): Observable<Date> {
    return this.ormService.manager$.pipe(
      switchMap(manager => manager.find(OfflineStatusEntity)),
      map(statusArr => statusArr[0]!.lastSync || new Date(0))
    );
  }
```

I start the synchronization in this function:

```js
synchronizeData(): Observable<void> {
    const syncDate = new Date();
    return this.fetchLastSyncDate().pipe(
      switchMap(modifiedAfter =>
        this.httpClient.get<SynchronizationDto>(
          `${this.baseUrl}/${DateTime.fromJSDate(modifiedAfter).toISO()}`
        )
      ),
      switchMap(data => from(this.updateDataFromServer(data, syncDate)))
    );
  }
```

And I update the sync date here:

```js
private async updateDataFromServer(
    data: SynchronizationDto,
    syncStart: Date
  ): Promise<void> {
    ...
     // save sync date
    const manager = (await firstValueFrom(this.ormService.dataSource$)).manager;
    const status = (await manager.find(OfflineStatusEntity))[0]!;
    status.lastSync = syncStart;
    await manager.save(status);
}
```

Finally I am trying to subscribe to `fetchLastSyncDate()` like this:

```js
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    subscription = new Subscription();
    lastSyncTime: string | null = null;

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.subscription.add(
        this.synchronzationDataService.fetchLastSyncDate().subscribe(newSyncDate => {
          this.lastSyncTime = newSyncDate.toLocaleString('de-CH');
          this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
        })
      );
    }
}
```

When I first open the app I get the correct time of the latest sync. However when I run the synchronization, the value of `lastSyncTime` is never updated. What am I missing?

I'm still pretty new to observables, so I am not sure I understood the concept of subscriptions correctly. I thought that by subscribing to a function that returns an observable this subscription would be triggered as soon as the observable's value changes. Is this not the case?

Comment: Can you please create a minimal repro on Stackblitz? For the service just return a mock observable. It'll be way easier to help you out.

Comment: Do not use async-await in Angular apps. ngZone does not work with async await.

Answer (score 1):

Observables are streams of data over time. An Oservable can do 3 things:

- notify data
- error
- complete
  Once complete an Observable can not notify any more.

http calls are a special case of Observables. They are streams that notify just once the data returned and then complete (or error if something bad occurs). The reason why it makes sense to map http calls as Observable is that, once fired, they notify the result asynchronously and therefore they represent "a stream of data over time".

If mapped as Observables, http calls are fired when the Observable is subscribed. Since, in your case, the subscription occurs in the `ngOnInit` method, then *"you get the time when you first open the app"*.

If you want *"get the correct time"* again, then you have somehow to run the following code again

```
    this.synchronzationDataService.fetchLastSyncDate().subscribe(newSyncDate => {
        this.lastSyncTime = newSyncDate.toLocaleString('de-CH');
        this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
}
```

I suspect that when you say that *"you run the synchronization"* again you mean that you subscribe to the Observable returned by `synchronizeData()`, but this would not be sufficient to do what you do in the `ngOnInit` code.